# Unable to drag drop components on AEM new page

Tags: java, osgi, aem, sling, wcm

I am following AEM tutorial [wknd tutorial](https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/experience-manager-learn/getting-started-wknd-tutorial-develop/project-archetype/component-basics.html?lang=en#component-authoring). I have created the project using archetype and installed it on local AEM instance. Unlike the tutorial when i create a new page i do not get the option to drag and drop components and neither am i able to find any components in side rail.
[image]

I went to the template to edit it in design mode and enable components but could not find design mode to edit it to enable components.
[image]

I am not sure what to do to follow along with the tutorial. Any help is much appreciated.

[image: system console]

Comment: Check what is the AEM version that you are using and check what is the uber-jar version in code that you have deployed, both should match.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve the issue by installing the wknd project again using -Pclassic option in the maven command. The project was designed for Cloud service but after reading the description in [github](https://github.com/adobe/aem-guides-wknd#building-for-aem-6xx) for AEM 6.x.x it worked.

**Building for AEM 6.x.x
The project has been designed for AEM as a Cloud Service. The project is also backward compatible with AEM 6.4.8 and 6.5.5 by adding the classic profile when executing a build, i.e:
mvn clean install -PautoInstallSinglePackage -Pclassic**

Comment: i am facing the same issue, even for newly created project for aem version 6.5.0. Any idea ?